# For joins in SQL, Is common column not compulsory?

Tags: sql

I came to know that we can use other than `JOIN ON a.col = b.col`, with `JOIN ON a.col CONDITION b.col2`. How does it works?.

Example:
2 Tables are:

[image]

[image]

We can join them as follows (ignoring the required output code, how is that join worked?)

```
SELECT Students.Name, Grades.Grade, Students.Marks FROM Students 
INNER JOIN Grades ON Students.Marks BETWEEN Grades.Min_Mark AND Max_Mark
WHERE Grades.Grade > 7 
ORDER BY Grades.Grade DESC, Students.Name ASC;
```

Comment: It works, because that is how SQL is specified. It will evaluate the condition for the rows and then match the rows where the condition evaluates to true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Joins don't have to nominate a column at all:

```
SELECT * FROM People CROSS JOIN Addresses
```

This combines all people with all addresses. If there were 2 people and 3 addresses, 6 records would result

```
Person.Name, Address.Name
-------------------------
Person1, Address1
Person1, Address2
Person1, Address3
Person2, Address1
Person2, Address2
Person2, Address3
```

Joins that have a condition don't have to use any columns from the sets of data being joined, they just have to evaluate to true in order for the row to appear in the output. You can consider that when a database is processing any join, it first produces the cross product of every row (like above) then the truth of the condition is checked per row to decide which of those rows make it into the output

First let's do a join on something that makes some sense, using the above data

```
SELECT * FROM People INNER JOIN Addresses ON Person.Name = Address.Name
```

That would produce nothing, because 'Person1' is never equal to 'Address1' and so on.. But suppose we altered it to:

```
SELECT * FROM People INNER JOIN Addresses ON REPLACE(Person.Name, 'Person', 'Address') = Address.Name
```

The 6 rows would be prepared like before:

```
Person1, Address1
Person1, Address2
Person1, Address3
Person2, Address1
Person2, Address2
Person2, Address3
```

The DB would replace the word Person with the word Address just while it was evaluating the truth of the join, and the tests would be performed:

```
Person1, Address1  --'Person1'->'Address1', does 'Address1'='Address1'? YES; OUTPUT the row
Person1, Address2  --'Person1'->'Address1', does 'Address1'='Address2'? no; discard the row
Person1, Address3  --'Person1'->'Address1', does 'Address1'='Address3'? no; discard the row
Person1, Address1  --'Person2'->'Address2', does 'Address2'='Address1'? no; discard the row
Person2, Address2  --'Person2'->'Address2', does 'Address2'='Address2'? YES; OUTPUT the row
Person2, Address3  --'Person2'->'Address2', does 'Address2'='Address3'? no; discard the row
```

So you get 2 rows:

```
Person1, Address1
Person2, Address2
```

Now let's make it really wacky; Suppose you had:

```
SELECT * FROM People INNER JOIN Addresses ON DAY_OF_WEEK(NOW()) = 'Monday'
```

The query would produce 6 rows, but only on Monday. As soon as it turned to Tuesday the query would produce 0 rows. It doesn't make much *sense* to do, but you're still allowed to do it. So long as you provide something the DB can evaluate to true, or false, the DB will join every row to every other row, then check the truth for every combination, and discard any combination if it sees a false

---

Imagine other scenarios. Person and Address are supposed to be related on Address having a PersonId

If you did:

```
SELECT * FROM People LEFT JOIN Addresses ON Person.Id = (Address.PersonId + 1)
```

You'd see:

```
PersonId, Name, Address_PersonId, Street
0,        Tim,  NULL,             NULL
1,        John, 0,                TheRoad
2,        Mary, 1,                TheAvenue
```

It's supposed to be Tim that lives at TheRoad, but we wrote a nonsensical join condition that was evaluated and churned out results anyway

You could divide the ID by 2, you could join on a random number being less than 0.5.. It doesn't matter, it's just a truth and most of the time it's at its most useful when it uses column data..

---

> how is that join worked?

This BETWEEN form is actually quite a useful one. It allows you to band loads of different scores into set bands.

Suppose you have 2 people scores and 3 bands (i'm keeping it small to make it easier to type out):

```
Name, Score
Tim, 79
John, 68

ScoreLower, ScoreHigher, Rating
0, 50, Bronze
51, 75, Silver
76, 100, Gold
```

And you do

```
SELECT * FROM People JOIN Scores ON Score BETWEEN ScoreLower AND ScoreHigher
```

Remember that the DB conceptually combines EVERY person with EVERY score band first:

```
Tim, 79, 0, 50, Bronze
Tim, 79, 51, 75, Silver
Tim, 79, 76, 100, Gold
John, 68, 0, 50, Bronze
John, 68, 51, 75, Silver
John, 68, 76, 100, Gold
```

And then it goes through knocking out the ones that aren't true

```
Tim, 79, 0, 50, Bronze   --FALSE, 79 is not BETWEEN 0 and 50, discard this one
Tim, 79, 51, 75, Silver  --FALSE, 79 is not BETWEEN 51 and 75, discard this one
Tim, 79, 76, 100, Gold   --TRUE, keep
John, 68, 0, 50, Bronze  --FALSE, discard
John, 68, 51, 75, Silver --TRUE, keep
John, 68, 76, 100, Gold  --FALSE, discard
```

And you get just the keeps:

```
Tim, 79, 76, 100, Gold   
John, 68, 51, 75, Silver
```

You could have a list of all the chinese astrological years, and a list of people with a known birthday, and then do their `birthday BETWEEN yearstart AND yearend` and find out if they're a Horse, Dog etc.. You could have a list of all the letters in the alphabet and a color, and put people into color groups based on the first letter of their name. It doesn't have to be `=`, we could use LIKE:

```
People JOIN AlphabetColors ON People.FirstName LIKE AlphabetColors.Letter + '%'
```

Or we could:

```
People JOIN AlphabetColors ON LEFT(People.FirstName, 1) = AlphabetColors.Letter
```

Either way, data like:

```
Albert
Bill
Charlie

A, Red
B, Green
C, Blue
```

Ends up as

```
Albert, A, Red
Bill, B, Green
Charlie, C, Blue
```

Comment: Side note, don't get too hung up on how the DB does what it does internally, because you'll start your mind boggling about how a table with a thousand rows, joined to a table with a million rows, produces a billion combinations that must be checked.. and how can it be so fast at checking etc. This answer isn't intended to say exactly how, internally, a DB implments joining - it's incredibly complicated.. The answer is intended to convey this conceptualization of how you get out what you get out, from what you put in